# Not able to put required names on Java

Tags: java

I have a text file:

```
Filename: apple.jpg
Name: Apple
Brief: Apple is a fruit

Filename: orange.jpg
Name: Orange
Brief: Orange is also a fruit

Filename: tomato.jpg
Name: Tomato
Brief: Tomato is not a fruit, it's a vegetable
```

I have a code:

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:/textLocation.txt"));

    String filename = "";
    String name = "";
    String brief = "";

    String line = "";
    while (reader.hasNextLine()){
        line = reader.nextLine();

        if (line.startsWith("Filename:") && (line.contains("apple"))){
            filename = line.substring(10, line.length());
        } else if (line.startsWith("Name:")){
            name = line.substring(6, line.length());
        } else if (line.startsWith("Brief:")){
            brief = line.substring(7, line.length());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(filename);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(brief);
}
}
```

The problem I am having is when I set apple, it makes Filename as apple.jpg, which is correct, but Name and Brief are tomato ones. How can I correct this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! Used David's suggestion and it worked.

Comment: Give a +1 to everyone as a way to acknowledge their effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:/textLocation.txt"));

        String filename = "";
        String name = "";
        String brief = "";
        boolean lookingForName = false;
        boolean lookingForBrief = false;

        String line = "";
        while (reader.hasNextLine()){
            line = reader.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("Filename:") && (line.contains("apple"))){
                filename = line.substring(10, line.length());
                lookingForName = true;
                lookingForBrief = true;
            } else if (line.startsWith("Name:") && lookingForName){
                name = line.substring(6, line.length());
                lookingForName = false;
            } else if (line.startsWith("Brief:") && lookingForBrief){
                brief = line.substring(7, line.length());
                lookingForBrief = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(brief);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all three items as you get them, you need to put the printing inside the loop. An easy way to decide when to print is to check that all three items are non-empty. Here is how you can do it:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()){
    line = reader.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("Filename:") && (line.contains("apple"))){
        filename = line.substring(10); // line.length() parameter is optional
    } else if (line.startsWith("Name:")){
        name = line.substring(6);
    } else if (line.startsWith("Brief:")){
        brief = line.substring(7);
    }
    // Decide if you want to print or not: see if we've got all three
    if (filename.length() != 0 && name.length() != 0 && brief.length() != 0) {
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(brief);
        System.out.println("--------");
        // Reset for the next iteration
        filename = "";
        name = "";
        brief = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your printlns outside the while loop. So the data is only printed after you have read the whole file.

The last two lines that contain Name and Brief are obviously "Tomato" so it prints them, the Filename you have restricted by checking for apple, hence that is not replaced by the next two filename lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic inside the while loop is wrong

Hint

Inside the `while` loop

Reads a line
check if line starts with "Filename:" and if it contains apple. Now it sets `filename` to `filename = line.substring(10, line.length());`.
it does not enter `else if` conditions as the `if` is true.

You see the problem ?

Comment: That is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your condition.

`line.startsWith("Filename:") && (line.contains("apple")`
In the above line, you fetch the filename of the fruit if and only if it is apple. If not, you just move on to get the other two lines.

The result is, when you get to orange and tomato, you skip reading their filenames and just read their name and brief. You need a change in your logic on how to retrieve the substrings.

To extract substrings, do not hardcode the positions for the start and end of the sub string. Instead, use `indexOf()` to retrieve the position of `:` and from the next position to the end, get substring.

---

```
public int indexOf(int ch)
```

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the
>   character sequence represented by this String object, then the index
>   of the first such occurrence is returned -- that is, the smallest
>   value k such that:
>
> ```
>  this.charAt(k) == ch
> ```
>
> is true. If no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is
>   returned.

---

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:/textLocation.txt"));

    String filename = "";
    String name = "";
    String brief = "";

    String line = "";
    while (reader.hasNextLine()){
        line = reader.nextLine();

        if (line.startsWith("Filename:") && (line.contains("apple"))){
            filename = line.substring(10, line.length());
        } else if (line.startsWith("Name:")){
            name = line.substring(6, line.length());
        } else if (line.startsWith("Brief:")){
            brief = line.substring(7, line.length());
        }
    }

   if(filename.equals("apple.jpg")){ // print only if you have apple. Else, ignore
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(brief);
   }

}
}
```

Comment: This program still has the same bug as the original program.  Run it and see!

Comment: @DavidWallace and the bug is... ?

Comment: OP says "The problem I am having is when I set apple, it makes Filename as apple.jpg, which is correct, but Name and Brief are tomato ones. How can I correct this?"  Your program still prints Name and Brief for a tomato.  Run it and see!